# Pythonpath only recognized in interactive teminal

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, path, pythonpath

The title really says it all. Files in my PYTHONPATH are not recognized when I run scripts (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <some_module>`), but they are when I open the interactive prompt in the command line. I'm running ubuntu 22.04. What could be causing this?

Comment: what do you really have in PYTHONPATH? it has be path to directory, not to file.

Comment: @furas Yes I have the directory there. It's weird because I have had this working before and I don't think I did anything differently. The fact that the interactive python prompt does recognize it just adds to the confusion.

Comment: you can use `os.getenv("PYTHONPATH")` to check what you have in variable when you run code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was caused by python cache directories in a parent directory of my script. I deleted them and now the path works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at that. Would be weird because it applies to scripts even in my home directory. but maybe.